# How to run exe in background process and communicate with that exe do all remaining activities with that exe

Tags: python, automation, background

We are trying to install firmware in device using third party exe. so we developed our own exe using python automation (pywinauto) it executing properly but I don't want to visible that third party exe in foreground. Please help to hide that third party exe and entire remaining process we need to run in background like loading firmware selecting device and clicking installation etc. One more thing we tried to hide exe using win32gui module and win32con module its working but it just hiding the exe the remaining process loading firmware, selecting device and installation not working.

Please provide better solution.

I don't want to visible that third party exe in foreground.tried to hide exe using win32gui module and win32con module its working but it just hiding the exe the remaining process loading firmware, selecting device and installation not working